# Optimize Elasticsearch update script body using python bulk update

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch

Consider this script:

```
hashed_ids = [hashlib.md5(doc.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for doc in shingles]
update_by_query_body =
{
  "query":{
    "terms": {
      "id":["id1","id2"]
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "source":"long weightToAdd = params.hashed_ids.stream().filter(idFromList -> ctx._source.id.equals(idFromList)).count(); ctx._source.weight += weightToAdd;",
    "params":{
      "hashed_ids":["id1","id1","id1","id2"]
    }
  }
}
```

This script does what it's supposed to do but it is very slow and from time to time raises time out error.

### What it's supposed to do?

I need to update a field of a doc in Elasticsearch and add the count of that doc in a list inside python code. The weight field contains the count of the doc in a dataset. The dataset needs to be updated from time to time. So the count of each document must be updated too. `hashed_ids` is a list of document ids that are in the new batch of data. the weight of matched id must be increased by the count of that id in `hashed_ids`.
for example let say a doc with `id=d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` and `weight=5` is already present in index. and also the string `d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` is repeated three times in the `hashed_ids` so the `update_with_query` query  will match the doc in database. I need to add 3 to 5 and have 8 as final `weight`.

---

I need ideas to improve the efficiency of the code.

Comment: Hi, in my view it is better to have your logic in your python code and use bulk update by the id of the document. For large data, you can use scroll for fetching data and you can use a bulk update for updating. Using a script in elasticsearch is always slow.

Comment: @saeednasehi Hey Saeed :))) Thank you very much